# Resolving Bonjour Discovery Dependencies

Tags: c++, bonjour, zeroconf

I have developed the a library to discover Device Using Bonjour Discovery Api.

I have installed bonjour sdk in my system so the Unit Test for it is working fine in my machine.

But When we run on fresh machine it is crashing.The reason for this Bonjour is not installed on that system.This library is going to be used in Some application.

My assumption is to run this library we not run mDNResponder.exe and mdnsNSP.dll.

One way to solve the problem is install the Bonjour SDk manually.

I am wanted to do it programatically.Please help me do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess need to run Bonjour.msi only Instead of SDK.